Can't get Numbers to sum up percentages correctly
I have a column with percentages; example:
8.3%
8.3%
8.3%
25%
25%
12.5%
12.5%

It should sum up to 99.99%, but Numbers produces a result of  0.75 for me,


Any ideas what's going on and how to fix?

Should it not sum up to 99.9%, or are you only displaying one decimal?

Make sure these are all numbers, and not plain text. Easy check: Make a column that multiplies these numbers by two. The text “25%”, multiplied by two, would probably give 0 as the result

"Works for me?"
I would format your numbers back to "Automatic" to check for any errant characters that could be throwing off the formatter.


But that is B3:B9

Solved by changing the format to Automatic or Percentage, nice catch. Some of these fields are Text, I copied from another document and didn't notice that!

@daisy By default, text in Excel is left-aligned and numbers are right-aligned. Assuming you haven't touched those defaults, you can tell the difference between this screenshot and yours.
